# How could triple is Measure Space

Tags: measure-theory, discrete-mathematics

What I know about Measure Space is if $(X,S)$ as measurable space and $(U)$ as measure then $(X,S,U)$ is measure space. Any else axioms as requirement? thanks

Comment: The connection is only that $U$ is defined on $S$, no more axioms are present.

Answer (score 3):

All that's necessary is that the measure be defined on the $\sigma$-algebra.